# Same variable, different name

Tags: java, for-loop

I am currently experimenting with Java since I am still learning the basics. 
I was wondering if it is possible in some way to use a for loop with variables.

Take this code as an example:

```
public class Var {

  public static void main(String[]args) {

    int num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    System.out.println("First dice: " + num1)

    int num2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    System.out.println("Second dice: " + num2);

    int num3 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    System.out.println("Third dice: " + num3);
  }
}
```

The following is how I picture the code using a for loop

```
public class Var {

  public static void main(String[]args){

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      int num(i) = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1; //Here i is the for loop
      System.out.println("num(i)");
     }
  }
}
```

Here obviously there are several syntax errors but is there a way of making a code similar to this?

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Learn about arrays.

Comment: Array allows you give same variable name to variables holding similar values.

Comment: In this case, you should use an array...

Comment: I've just looked it up... so instead of num(i) I use num[ i ] ?

Comment: java doesn't allow dynamic variable name like  `String num+1;`

Comment: You only need arrays, if you want to access the values outside the loop. If you only need the values inside, then you can simply do `int num = (int) (Math.random() * (6)+1;`

Comment: @Downvoters add a comment to explain to Star what he did wrong, and what to better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You're looking for the array syntax:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

```
int[] accumulator = new int[3]; // create a new array
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // loop 
    int num = (int) (Math.random() * (6)+1); 
    accumulator[i] = num; // assign the random number 
   System.out.println(accumulator[i]); // print to console
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You can print 3 random numbers with a few minor alterations to your loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    int num = (int) (Math.random() * (6)) + 1;
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

or if you want to store them, use an `array` of some sort:

```
int[] array = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int num = (int) (Math.random() * (6)) + 1;
    array[i] = num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using the `Random` class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] randomNumbers = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            int num = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
            randomNumbers[i] = num;
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }
}
```